# ShoppingCart and Item Classes

Tags: c++, pointers

I've built a class for an e-commerce `Item`, and the `ShoppingCart` class for checkout functions.

The thing I'm most concerned about is my use of pointers.  I *think* I've used them properly in this situation, but I could be wrong.

**Item.hpp**

```
#ifndef Item_hpp
#define Item_hpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Item {

private:
    string name;
    double price;
    int quantity;

public:
    void setName(string);
    void setPrice(double);
    void setQuantity(int);
    string getName();
    double getPrice();
    int getQuantity();

    // Constructors
    Item();

    Item(string, double, int);

};

#endif
```

**Item.cpp**

```
#include "Item.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Item::Item() {
    name = "";
    price = 0.0;
    quantity = 0;
}

Item::Item(string itemName, double itemPrice, int itemQuantity) {
    setName(itemName);
    setPrice(itemPrice);
    setQuantity(itemQuantity);
}

void Item::setName(string itemName) {
    name = itemName;
}

void Item::setPrice(double itemPrice) {
    price = itemPrice;
}

void Item::setQuantity(int itemQuantity) {
    quantity = itemQuantity;
}

string Item::getName() {
    return name;
}

double Item::getPrice() {
    return price;
}

int Item::getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
```

**ShoppingCart.hpp**

```
#ifndef ShoppingCart_hpp
#define ShoppingCart_hpp

#include "Item.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ShoppingCart {

private:
    Item* itemArray[100];
    int arrayEnd;

public:
    void addItem(Item *);
    double totalPrice();

    // Constructors
    ShoppingCart();

};
#endif
```

**ShoppingCart.cpp**

```
#include "ShoppingCart.hpp"
#include "Item.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

ShoppingCart::ShoppingCart() {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        itemArray[i] = {NULL};
    }
    arrayEnd = 0;
}

void ShoppingCart::addItem(Item *currentItem) {
    itemArray[arrayEnd] = currentItem;
    arrayEnd++;
}

double ShoppingCart::totalPrice() {
    double totalPrice;

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        if (itemArray[i] != NULL) {
            totalPrice += itemArray[i]->getPrice() * itemArray[i]->getQuantity();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return totalPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `using namespace std` is [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- Unrestricted getters and setters are as good as making `Item`'s members public. In fact, if there is no class invariant to maintain, do make them public.
- `arrayEnd` is not a particularly good name. Consider calling it `items` (or `items_count`) instead. As a side note, use it!

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
      total_price += whatever;
  ```

  This way the shopping cart constructor reduces to

  ```
  ShoppingCart() {
      items = 0;
  }
  ```
- `totalPrice` is not initialized.
- Having pointers in the shopping card is a dubious decision. You must answer the question *who owns items*. In other words, who's responsibility is to destroy `Item`, and what happens to the cart when it *is* destroyed? I strongly recommend to either have the cart to keep *objects*, or make cart responsible for their construction and destruction.

Comment: Interesting point about namespace pollution, I didn't realize that.  I included the setters/getters, and used pointers only because that was part of the assignment requirements for school, but it's good to know that a design spec given by a teacher doesn't necessarily follow best practices :)

Answer (score 2):

While I think @vnp has the right idea, I'd go a bit further: there's no point (excuse the pun) in using pointers here.

There's also no point in creating your own dynamic array when there's a perfectly good one in the standard library (`std::vector`).

Your `item` class is much longer and clumsier to use, but ultimately provides no advantage over just:

```
struct item { 
    string name;
    double price;
    int quantity;
};
```

...and possibly having a default constructor to initialize the price/quantity to 0.

Your `ShoppingCart` is nearly equivalent to just a `std::vector<item>`, with one extra function to add up the prices of items in the cart. For that I'd probably write code something like this:

```
typedef std::vector<item> ShoppingCart;

double total_price(ShoppingCart const &cart) { 
    return std::accumulate(cart.begin(), cart.end(), 0.0, 
               [](double a, item const &i) { return a + i.price * i.quantity; });
}
```

When writing classes, keep the bottom line in mind. The intent is not to just write more code to do the same things. The real intent is to provide a higher level of abstraction that simplifies code that uses the class. In this case, that doesn't seem to be happening much (if at all). You're adding a lot of code, but in the end, most of that code is just doing what can/would happen by default if you didn't write anything. In such a case, either find something better to do, or else just don't do it.

If you wanted to think about the "something better" to do, I can see a few obvious possibilities. First would be for `Item` to provide some `TotalPrice` sort of thing that handles multiplying the unit price by the quantity to get the total price. Likewise, the ShoppingCart could compute a shipping price based on the total number of items, a weight for each, and (if you wanted to get really elaborate) codes for the source and destination for each as well. Add in a Catalog that keeps track of the number of units available so a person *can't* add more items to their shopping cart than there are available, and we're starting to add enough intelligence that the classes stand a good chance of really accomplishing something.